# How to use if statement to merge cells depending on selected value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am a photographer and I want to create a weekly time sheet for my photo shoot bookings. Some sessions are 1 hour long, some are 2 hours, 4 hours... etc. So I created a table and a dropdown list including all my photo shoot packs (the list is in a separate sheet).

[image: Screenshot of the table]

As you can see, since each row represents 1 hour, I want to merge the cells with the sessions that are longer than 1 hour. For example, Pack #2 is 2 hours long. When I select it, I want to merge it with the cell below so 2 rows (2 hours) are booked for this session.

Example of how I want it to be:

[image: Screenshot of how I want it to be]

Also, I am struggling to assign a numerical value inside each photo shoot pack so I can use a `SUM()` function to return the total earning per day and week. For example, when Pack #1 is selected, I want the cell to have a value of $125.

I do not know if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the pricing to work is very easy. You just need to insert a helper column in your time sheet and expand your dropdown list data to include the prices:

[image: Screenshot of time sheet]

[image: Screenshot of data sheet]

Enter this formula in `C2` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>/fill/copy-paste it into `C2:C7`:

```dart
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Lists!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE),0)
```

Enter this formula in `B8`:

```dart
=SUM(C1:C8)
```

Note that the helper column can be hidden and it will still work.

---

Auto-merging the cells appropriately is a bit trickier and requires a VBA solution. (I'll see if I can whip one up.)

Comment: Thank you so much! The calculation worked perfectly. Still waiting if you have any idea about auto-merging. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Lolee I've just about finished the auto-merging VBA code. It's relatively straightforward, but there's a lot of edge-cases and a few Excel bugs to work around. I've got it working, just need to finish testing it. (I got distracted by other things.) I really should go to bed now, though. It'll have to wait 'til tomorrow.